# How to set zoom multiple times with Google Maps API v3?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, zooming

I have a Google map like so:

```
var map_options = {        
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    streetViewControl: false
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, map_options);
```

I perform an ajax call that puts some markers on the map and in that call's `beforeSend` I change the zoom level of the map based on the place the user selects. This is all fine and dandy..

```
$.ajax({
    url: myServiceUrl,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    beforeSend: function () {                    
        setMapZoom();
    },            
    success: function (data) {
        //do work
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
    }            
});

function setMapZoom() {    
    var z_level = getMapZoomLevel(googleplace.geometry.viewport);
    map.setCenter(googleplace.geometry.location);
    map.setZoom(z_level);
}
```

At first this wasn't working at all because the map api's calls are async.. so that's why I put the zoom method in the `beforeSend`.

However, NOW my issue is that it only performs the zoom ONE TIME. I load the map on say Toronto, ON, Canada - it goes and centers on Toronto and zooms to level 5 - perfect.

Then I change to Miami, FL, USA - it centers on Miami just fine, but it determines the zoom to be level 9 (not 5) calls map.setZoom(9) - but the zoom stays at 5.

I appreciate any feedback. :)

Thanks!

Comment: I think your code do setZoom(9) during the map still loading tiles.

Comment: The setMapZoom() function is called before the markers are even requested though..

Comment: I see. Could you give me a link of your page?

Comment: I actually can't due to a Non Disclosure Agreement. Is there any other information I might be able to provide that could help you? I could list the work flow of the page in detail if that helps.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/welcome/48301 - it works as I want it to :/ So I believe that wf is correct when he says the markers are loading during the setZoom.. any thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You have  the viewport desired, why don't you use it?

```
map.fitBounds(googleplace.geometry.viewport);
```

Comment: I have tried this. I believe now after setting this up in jsbin that the first commenter is correct. The loading of markers is taking too long.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED:**

As it turns out.. a fellow coder here was calling some code to clear user defined listeners on the zoom event. He didn't know this also clear Google defined listeners.. :)

Maybe this will help someone in the future.